# Checking file existence and reading in using Directory and GetFiles

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, directory

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong in the following code that, in the `Unity standalone` mode, my intended `xml` file is not read in?

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR

if( Directory.Exists( ApplicationManager.ExperimentPath ) )
{
    texts = Directory.GetFiles( ApplicationManager.ExperimentPath, "*.xml" );
}
else
{
    texts = new string[0];
}

#elif UNITY_STANDALONE

if( Directory.Exists( Application.streamingAssetsPath ) )
{
    texts = Directory.GetFiles( Application.streamingAssetsPath, "*.xml" );
}
else
{
    texts = new string[0];
}

#else

Debug.Log("Platform not supported yet!");

#endif
```

The `xml` file that contains my program data is placed in the `build_Data` directory...

Comment: Yes, I do. The standard `StreamingAssets` folder is there, with the `xml` files inside. I thought perhaps in the `standalone` I shouldn' use `GetFiles` or `Directory` and maybe I should use `StreamReader` ???

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html

Comment: I am actually trying to achieve this in one line, similar to the one meant for the EDITOR. Something similar to `texts = Directory.GetFiles(ApplicationManager.ExperimentPath, "*.xml");` Basically, reading in the whole `xml` file, rather than the typical C# style for `StreamReader` Is it possible to do this?